# twitter-bootstrap align search image to next to input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to align image next to input field using bootstrap,

I applied in the following way, but so much blank space is displaying.

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label">Account Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">    
            <button class="btn-icon btn-icon-print"><img src="images/search.png"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

image snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are seperating your columns... you see, your button is an own md-1 column, while your bar is an md-3 column... between every column is a 15px margin (total of 30) on left and right. Better do it different.

Something like maybe

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-9 margin-fix">
      <label class="control-label">Account Number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 margin-fix">    
      <button class="btn-icon btn-icon-print"><img src="images/search.png"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<style>
  .margin-fix {margin-left, margin-right: 0px;}
</style>
```

This way you wrap it inside the col-md-3. Still you have now a margin problem, however since I applied a margin-fix on your elements, it shouldn't be registering the margin, and thus put it all next to each other.

You can make it bigger by changing it to a col-md-4. You use the col-md-3 actually now as a container to wrap it in, and it will all scale with the size of the column you apply.

edit.

if you seek to have the button inline, look at bootstraps layout

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
</div>
```

The input group is a very cool feature which allows items to be "wrapped" within the element.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons